# Weird behavior with the logical and operator in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, logical-operators

This will be the first question I post here, please advise me if anything is wrong.

So I get this piece of C code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    char array[3][50] = {
        "theoretical computer science",
        "programming puzzles and code golf",
        "ebooks"
    };
    int randIdx = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        // discard everything longer than 27
        while((randIdx = rand() % 3) && (strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27));

        printf("outside while: randIdx = [%d]\tstrlen = [%ld]\n",
                randIdx, strlen(array[randIdx]));
    }

}
```

[Since the order of the logical and operator is left to right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx), I was hoping that the empty while loop will be able to discard the first and second array member. However, the output of the program (looped 10 times) looks like this:

```
outside while: randIdx = [2]    strlen = [6]
outside while: randIdx = [0]    strlen = [28]
outside while: randIdx = [0]    strlen = [28]
outside while: randIdx = [0]    strlen = [28]
outside while: randIdx = [2]    strlen = [6]
outside while: randIdx = [2]    strlen = [6]
outside while: randIdx = [2]    strlen = [6]
outside while: randIdx = [2]    strlen = [6]
outside while: randIdx = [0]    strlen = [28]
outside while: randIdx = [0]    strlen = [28]
```

Any idea why `randIdx = [0] strlen = [28]` can escape the while loop?

Comment: Perhaps the semicolon following your `while` loop  has something to do with it.

Comment: You are asking why while loop terminates when condition is false.......may be because `strlen = [28]` dosent satisfy 2nd condition of `And`  `strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27`.

Comment: @wrangler - You are right, I made a mistake and did not realize `(randIdx = rand() % 3)` equals to `(randIdx = rand() % 3) != 0`. The empty while body was intended to skip the `randIdx` that point to array members longer than 27.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those cases where you actually *want* to use the comma operator:

```
while (randIdx = rand() % 3 , strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27))
    ;
```

in order to both perform the assignment and ignore its result.

I would make a note that it's meant to be like that, so nobody tries to "correct" it in the future.

It's also a good idea to make intentionally empty loops look intentional, either with the semicolon on its own line, or by being even more explicit:

```
while (randIdx = rand() % 3 , strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27))
{
    /* Empty loop */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `while` statement loops as long as the condition is truthy. In the cases of `randIdx == 0` & `strlen(array[randIdx]) < 27`, the expression is false (`0`), and the `while` loop is stopped.

So, if you wanted to only let `randIdx` values such that `randIdx != 0` *and* that `strlen(array[randIdx]) < 28`, you could reverse the logic and use ***logical OR*** instead:

```
while(!(randIdx = rand() % 3) || (strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27));
```

This will continue generating new random values as long as `randIdx` is 0 *OR* the length is >= 27.

Effectively, only `randIdx = [2] strlen = [6]` will go through.

Comment: Also the `while` loop has no body, therefore it does nothing, other than change the value of `randIdx`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly - I suspect that's the intention

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the mistake I made in the code immediately after I posted the question. `(randIdx = rand() % 3)` equals to `(randIdx = rand() % 3) != 0`. which is not what I intended to here.

Comment: @JonnyHenly - My intention was to use an empty while body to skip the `randIdx` that point to array members longer than 27.

Comment: @Amit wasn't me, I realized the intention after looking closer, and your answer is correct.

Comment: It's such a shame people downvote without explaining why. Most of the time that comes from *lack* of understanding, the question & the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (i=0; i<10; i++) 
   {
        // discard everything longer than 27
        while((randIdx = rand() % 3) && (strlen(array[randIdx]) < 27))
        {
            printf("outside while: randIdx = [%d]\tstrlen = [%ld]\n", randIdx, strlen(array[randIdx]));
        }
    }
```

Maybe you can modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon(`;`) directly following your `while` loop. Making your while loop do nothing other than change the value of `randIdx`. You should change your code to:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

    // discard everything longer than 27
    while((randIdx = rand() % 3) && (strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27)) {
        printf("outside while: randIdx = [%d]\tstrlen = [%ld]\n",
            randIdx, strlen(array[randIdx]));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

while((randIdx = rand() % 3) && (strlen(array[randIdx]) >= 27));

In this  case of `randIdx = [0] strlen = [28]` if you check the condition inside the while loop then randIDX is equal to 0.
Which means while(0 && 1) ----> Here 1 is returned for strlen(array[randIdx])=28 which is greater than 27.

Hence I believe this answers the question

> why randIdx = [0] strlen = [28] can escape the while loop?